# Entity Framework 5 not adding foreign key

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have two tables in a SQL Server 2012 Express database that are defined like this.

SampleTableOne
ColumnName nvarchar(50) Primary Key
Id int

SampleTableTwo
Id int Primary Key
ColumnName nvarchar(50)

When I add a foreign key using the following command

```
ALTER TABLE SampleTableOne
ADD FOREIGN KEY(Id) REFERENCES SampleTableTwo(Id)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO
```

However when I add the models into Entity Framework, it is not adding the foreign key. I have "Include Foreign Key Columns In The Model" selected. Is there a step I am missing?

EDIT:

I am aiming for a one to one relationship.

Comment: A suggestion: Name and number are SQL server reserved keyword. It s not a good to use as table column name. Your DBA would not like it

Comment: I just used the numbers as example names, Ill change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the third [part](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/01/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx) and  [sixth part](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/17/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-6-many-valued-associations.aspx) of [Associations in EF Code First](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/17/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-6-many-valued-associations.aspx) saw the limitations of shared primary key association and argued that this type of association is relatively rare and in many schemas, a one-to-one and to Many-valued  association is represented with a foreign key field and a unique constraint.

Comment: A many-valued entity association is by definition a collection of entity references. One-to-many associations are the most important kind of entity association that involves a collection. We go so far as to discourage the use of more exotic association styles when a simple bidirectional many-to-one/one-to-many will do the job. A many-to-many association may always be represented as two many-to-one associations to an intervening class. This model is usually more easily extensible, so we tend not to use many-to-many associations in applications

Comment: This is supposed to be a one-to-one, does the same still hold true?